# Flex Ant compile project

Tags: apache-flex, ant, flexbuilder

i want to use Ant task to compile flex project(with many libraries, modules)

i use -dump-config build.xml compiler option in flash builder to extract build config

after i create this Ant task(for start, i try to compile only one mxml-module) :

```
<project name="My App Builderrrr" basedir="." default="main">

<property name="QA_PM_DEST" value="[my project dir]\src"/>
<property name="BIN_DEBUG" value="[my project dir]\bin-debug"/>
<property name="FLEX_HOME" value="C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4/sdks/4.0.0"/>
<property name="APP_ROOT" value="src"/>
<property name="DEPLOY_DIR" value="c:\output"/>


<taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${basedir}/libs/flexTasks.jar"/>

<target name="main">

     <mxmlc  file="${QA_PM_DEST}/***.mxml"
        output="${DEPLOY_DIR}/***.swf">
         <load-config filename="***\build.xml"/>

     </mxmlc>


</target>
```

and after

```
ant -buldfile mybuildfile.xml
```

but it generates very small swf file that runs with errors(67kb insted of 300kb in release build and 800kb in debug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to load the following config, too:

```
<property name="flex.config" value="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
<load-config filename="${flex.config}" />
```

**(UPDATE 2010-08-19)**

I also add `incremental="false"` to my mxmlc call and the libraries this way:

```
<library-path dir="${lib.dir}" append="true">
    <include name="**.swc" />
</library-path>
```

An the following is also missing in your file:

```
<source-path path-element="${src.dir}"/>
```

Comment: is there the way to extract ant build task and true build.xml that uses flash builder to compile current project?

Comment: i tried to write <mxmlc><load-config filename="***\build.xml" /><load-config filename="${flex.config}" /> and the compilere returned error aboud unexist classes. Next i added (in build.xml) libraries wrapped in <include-library> tag. It compiles successfully, but in browser it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean with "extract ant build task and true build.xml"? You write the build.xml yourself. If you want to get the configurations with FlashBuilder compiles your project: IMHO this isn't possible. FlashBuilder actually don't compile with ant (unless you say FlashBuilder to do so).
Have you specified the `${flex.config}` well? It has to be something like: `C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder/sdks/4.0.0/frameworks/flex-config.xml`

Comment: Unfortunately you can't generate a build.xml file from flex builder 3 (don't know about flash builder). Also, you have to note that flex builder doesn't use mxmlc when compiling projects.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! 2hering: yes, i specified correctly flex-config and it loads. 
2bug-a-lot: it's interisting for me hear whence you have learnt about it

Comment: I' ve updated my answer with new possible solutions. (code as comment wasn't really readable :()